# Initial algebra for rose trees

Tags: haskell, recursion, algebra, algebraic-data-types, category-theory

As far as I understand, recursive data types from Haskell correspond to initial algebras of endofunctors from the `Hask` category [[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_algebra#Use_in_computer_science), [2](https://bartoszmilewski.com/2017/02/28/f-algebras/)]. For example:

- Natural numbers, `data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat`, correspond to the initial algebra of the endofunctor `F(-) = 1 + (-)`.
- Lists, `data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a)`, correspond to the initial algebra of the endofunctor `F(A, -) = 1 + A × (-)`.

However, it's not clear to me what the endofunctor corresponding to the rose trees should be:

```
data Rose a = Node a (List (Rose a))
```

What confuses me is that there are two recursions: one for the rose tree and the other for the list. According to my calculations, I would get the following functor, but it doesn't seem right:

```
F(A, •, -) = A × (1 + (-) × (•))
```

---

Alternatively, rose trees can be defined as mutually recursive data types:

```
data Rose a   = Node a (Forest a)
type Forest a = List (Rose a)
```

Do mutually recursive data types have an interpretation in category theory?

Comment: Sure, you can write `RoseF(A,-) = A * List(-)` where `List(A)= μ (ListF(A))`, but I'm guessing you're looking for a non-recursive algebra. If so, there is no such algebra (in `Set->Set`). Perhaps it exists in another category (consider your statement: "there are two recursions")? This property of lacking a non-recursive algebra makes a type *non-regular* (or *non-uniform*, or *nested*, perhaps others..). Note this has nothing to do with mutual recursion (and `Rose` is only mutually recursive in a trivial way, since `Forest` is the identity).

Comment: Thanks for the comments, but I'm a bit confused because [this reference](https://books.google.ro/books?id=MN6kjutl2BcC&lpg=PA77&ots=xddEU9qtIc&dq=rose%20tree%20non%20regular%20data%20types&pg=PA77#v=onepage&q=rose%20tree%20non%20regular%20data%20types&f=false) suggests that rose trees are a regular data type ("a recursive, parameterised type whose recursive definition does not involve a change of the type parameter").

Comment: My motivation for looking for the initial algebra of the rose trees was to help me derive properties of rose tree, such as, the universal property of fold or the fusion law. @user2407038 Is your formulation based on the recursive algebra sufficient in this regard?

Comment: The type above is indeed regular (I misread it, first -- I deleted my misleading comments).

Comment: You got *Jeremy Gibbons* to join SO to remark on your question. You should be proud.

Comment: @dfeuer Ha-ha :-) I was indeed very pleasantly surprised to see Prof. Gibbons answer, especially since my inquiry into the world of initial algebras and rose trees started with his [Origami Programming](https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/jeremy.gibbons/publications/origami.pdf) paper and his [Categories for the Working Programmer](https://skillsmatter.com/skillscasts/5787-categories-for-the-working-haskeller) talk. Maybe this is a good time to thank Prof. Gibbons for his work, which I always find interesting and highly instructive :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would discourage talk of "the Hask Category" because it subconsciously conditions you against looking for other categorical structure in Haskell programming.

Indeed, rose trees can be seen as the fixpoint of an endofunctor on types-and-functions, a category which we might be better to call `Type`, now that `Type` is the type of types. If we give ourselves some of the usual functor kit...

```
newtype K a   x = K a deriving Functor           -- constant functor
newtype P f g x = P (f x, g x) deriving Functor  -- products
```

...and fixpoints...

```
newtype FixF f = InF (f (FixF f))
```

...then we may take

```
type Rose a = FixF (P (K a) [])
pattern Node :: a -> [Rose a] -> Rose a
pattern Node a ars = InF (P (K a, ars))
```

The fact that `[]` is itself recursive does not prevent its use in the formation of recursive datatypes via `Fix`. To spell out the recursion explicitly, we have nested fixpoints, here with bound variable names chosen suggestively:

```
Rose a = μrose. a * (μlist. 1 + (rose * list))
```

Now, by the time we've arrived in the second fixpoint, we have a type formula

```
1 + (rose * list)
```

which is functorial (indeed, strictly positive) in both `rose` and `list`. One might say it is a `Bifunctor`, but that's unnecessary terminology: it's a functor from `(Type, Type)` to `Type`. You can make a `Type -> Type` functor by taking a fixpoint in the second component of the pair, and that's just what happened above.

The above definition of `Rose` loses an important property. It is not true that

```
Rose :: Type -> Type   -- GHC might say this, but it's lying
```

merely that `Rose x :: Type` if `x :: Type`. In particular,

```
Functor Rose
```

is not a well typed constraint, which is a pity, as intuitively, rose trees ought to be functorial in the elements they store.

You can fix this by building `Rose` as itself being the fixpoint of a `Bifunctor`. So, in effect, by the time we get to lists, we have *three* type variables in scope, `a`, `rose` and `list`, and we have functoriality in all of them. You need a *different* fixpoint type constructor, and a *different* kit for building `Bifunctor` instances: for `Rose`, life gets easier because the `a` parameter is not used in the inner fixpoint, but in general, to define bifunctors as fixpoints requires trifunctors, and off we go!

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45257691/828361) of mine shows how to fight the proliferation by showing how *indexed* types are *closed* under a fixpoint-of-functor construction. That's to say, work not in `Type` but in `i -> Type` (for the full variety of index types `i`) and you're ready for mutual recursion, GADTs, and so on.

So, zooming out, rose trees are given by mutual fixpoints, which have a perfectly sensible categorical account, provided you see which categories are actually at work.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why `Rose :: Type -> Type` was lost in the first definition?

Comment: When you write *something* :: *Sometype*, you assert that the *something* is a thing. When you define `Rose a` as a `type` synonym, you define all the substitution instances of `Rose a`, but you do not define `Rose` itself. Similarly, `Functor Rose` is ill formed, as `Rose` is unapplied. If you define unapplied `Rose` by `type` or `Rose a` as a `data` type, then you do get that `Rose` itself is a thing and has type `Type -> Type`.

Answer (score 7):

This is not really an answer to the question you're asking, but perhaps interesting anyway. Note that with

```
Rose a = a * List (Rose a)
List a = 1 + a * List a
```

and the fact that `*` distributes over `+`, you have

```
  Rose a 
=   {- definition of `Rose` -}
  a * List (Rose a)
=   {- definition of `List` -}
  a * (1 + Rose a * List (Rose a))
=   {- `*` distributes over `+` -}
  a + a * Rose a * List (Rose a)
=   {- `*` is commutative -}
  a + Rose a * a * List (Rose a)
=   {- definition of `Rose` -}
  a + Rose a * Rose a
```

(the equality really denotes isomorphism). So you might as well have defined

```
Rose a = a + Rose a * Rose a
```

or in Haskell,

```
data Rose a = Leaf a | Bin (Rose a) (Rose a)
```

Which is to say, rose trees are isomorphic to ordinary (leaf-labelled) binary trees, and which clearly form a normal initial algebra.

Comment: How far can you go with the commutativity of `*`? Can you end up with performance problems rearranging too much?

Comment: This transformation certainly changes complexity. You can see it as a "spine representation" of a binary trees - for example, the "right spine representation" splits the tree along all the right edges, into a list of left children (each itself a tree) and one last element. Then you can get fast access to the "bottom right corner" of the tree.

Answer (score 2):

As you noticed, the definition of the functor for `Rose a` is trickier due to the fact that the recursive occurrence of the type is fed into a `List`. The problem is that `List` is itself a recursive type obtained as a fixed point. `List (Rose a)` basically corresponds to an "arbitrary number of elements of `Rose a`", something that you cannot express with a signature of products and sums alone, hence the need for additional abstraction over these multiple recursive points.

A functor `F A - : * -> *` will not work, as we would need to find something such that

```
F A X ≃ A × (1 + X × List X)
F A X ≃ A × (1 + X × (1 + X × List X))
F A X ≃ A × (1 + X × (1 + X × (1 + X × List X)))
...
```

One way to do it is to just treat `List` as primitive. Then `Rose a` is just the fixed point of

```
RoseF A : * -> * = λ X . A × List X
```

Another, more interesting way is to follow the suggestion in the reference you posted, and notice that the type of `Rose a` can be generalized to abstract over the functor in which the recursive occurrence is fed into

```
GRose F A ≃ A × F (GRose F A)
```

now `GRose` has type `(* -> *) -> (* -> *)`, hence it is an higher order functor mapping an endofunctor into another one. In our example, it would map the functor `List` into the type of rose trees.

Notice however that GRose is still recursive, so the above is actually stating an isomorphism rather than a solution to our problem. We can try to fix (wink wink) this by additionally abstracting over the recursive point

```
HRose G F A = A × F (G F A)
```

Notice that now `HRose` is a regular higher-order functor of type `((* -> *) -> (* -> *)) -> (* -> *) -> (* -> *)`, hence it maps higher-order functors into higher-order functors. Computing the least fixed point of `HRose` gives us

```
μ(HRose) F A ≃ A × F (μ(HRose) F A)
```

So if we put `Rose ≡ μ(HRose) List`, we get

```
Rose A ≃ A × List (Rose A)
```

which is exactly the defining equation for rose trees.
You can find many further examples of the theory and practice of generic programming using fixed points over higher-order functors. [Here](http://www.staff.city.ac.uk/~ross/papers/gfold.html), for example, Bird and Paterson develop it in the context of nested datatypes (but the definitions clearly hold in general). They also show the systematic construction of folds over datatypes defined in such way, as well as various laws.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to understand how this is modelled

```
data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a)
```

by taking, for any given `A`, the initial algebra of the endofunctor `F(A, -) = 1 + A × (-)`. Let's call this initial algebra `L(A)`.

If we forget the morphism in `L(A)`, we can sat that `L(A)` is an object of our category. Better, `L(-)` is not only a mapping from objects to objects, but can be seen as an endofunctor.

Once `L` is seed as an endofunctor, the recursive type

```
data Rose a = Node a (List (Rose a))
```

is interpreted by taking, for any `A`m the initial algebra of the functor

```
G A = A * L A
```

which is a functor obtained by composing `L` and `*` (and the diagonal functor).
Hence, the same approach works.